# const char compiler optimization

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, string-interning

I have global const char definition in two different files:

f1:

```
const char foo1[] = "SAME_VALUE";
```

f2:

```
const char foo2[] = "SAME_VALUE";
```

Wanted to understand if in the final binary this will be optimized to take common space in memory. This is in context of GCC

Comment: Tht depends on the compiler.  MSVC will optimize string literals (they call it string pooling) using the /GF switch.  Maybe someone else can provide an answer for gcc and clang.

Comment: This is in context of GCC, updated the description

Comment: It's woth to note how the subtleness of this question resides in the `const` keyword.It's not `char * foo` vs. `char foo[]`, the first being constant and the second modifiable. The question is about `const char foo[]`: will the const keyword be enough to make the compile understand it can be treated as `char *foo`?

Comment: The string literals themselves are likely only stored once. This optimization technique is called _string pooling_. I don't remember the gcc switch for enabling/disabling it.

Comment: What kind of software are you coding? What would happen to you if a common space is not used? How many weeks of efforts can you spend on that optimization? Do you have access to all the C code?

Comment: Code is being generated by a tool/script and there are many such constants and files. If the compiler doesn't take care of it then tool needs to be enhanced to use a common pool.

Comment: The easiest approach is to improve that tool/script (using some [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) database at build time). Also, don't comment your own question, but edit it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of optimization is called [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

GCC sets the `-fmerge-constants` flag by default:

> Attempt to merge identical constants (string constants and floating-point constants) across compilation units.
> This option is the default for optimized compilation if the assembler and linker support it. Use -fno-merge-constants to inhibit this behavior.
> Enabled at levels -O, -O2, -O3, -Os.

Let's make an executable with a 3rd file named *f.c* to reference the strings:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// For proposition#1
extern const char foo1[], foo2[];

// For proposition#2
//extern const char *foo1, *foo2;

int main(void) {

  printf("%s\n", foo1);
  printf("%s\n", foo2);

  return 0;
}
```

When you define the following respectively in *f1.c* and *f2.c* (**proposition#1**):

```c
const char foo1[] = "SAME_VALUE";
```

```c
const char foo2[] = "SAME_VALUE";
```

This results in 2 different memory spaces into which the string "SAME_VALUE" is stored. So, the string is duplicated:

```
$ gcc f.c f1.c f2.c
$ objdump -D a.out
[...]
0000000000001060 <main>:
    1060:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1064:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
    1068:   48 8d 3d 99 0f 00 00    lea    0xf99(%rip),%rdi <-- foo1@2008
    106f:   e8 dc ff ff ff          callq  1050 <puts@plt>
    1074:   48 8d 3d 9d 0f 00 00    lea    0xf9d(%rip),%rdi <-- foo2@2018
    107b:   e8 d0 ff ff ff          callq  1050 <puts@plt>
[...]
0000000000002008 <foo1>:
    2008:   53        'S'  <-- 1 string @ 2008
    2009:   41        'A'
    200a:   4d        'M' 
    200b:   45 5f     'E' '_'
    200d:   56        'V'
    200e:   41        'A'
    200f:   4c 55     'L' 'U'
    2011:   45        'E'
    ...

0000000000002018 <foo2>:
    2018:   53        'S'  <-- Another string @ 2018
    2019:   41        'A' 
    201a:   4d        'M' 
    201b:   45 5f     'E' '_'
    201d:   56        'V'
    201e:   41        'A'
    201f:   4c 55     'L' 'U' 
    2021:   45        'E'
```

But if you define the following respectively in *f1.c* and *f2.c* (**proposition#2**):

```c
const char *foo1 = "SAME_VALUE";
```

```c
const char *foo2 = "SAME_VALUE";
```

You define two pointers which will point on the same string. In this case, "SAME_VALUE" will likely not be duplicated. In the following raw disassembly, the string is at address 2004 and both *foo1* and *foo2* point to it:

```
$ gcc f.c f1.c f2.c
$ objdump -D a.out
[...]
    2004:   53        'S'    <-- 1 string @ 2004
    2005:   41        'A'
    2006:   4d        'M'
    2007:   45 5f     'E' '_'
    2009:   56        'V'
    200a:   41        'A'
    200b:   4c 55     'L' 'U'
    200d:   45        'E'
[...]
0000000000001060 <main>:
    1060:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1064:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
    1068:   48 8b 3d a1 2f 00 00    mov    0x2fa1(%rip),%rdi <-- 106f+2fa1=foo1@4010 
    106f:   e8 dc ff ff ff          callq  1050 <puts@plt>
    1074:   48 8b 3d 9d 2f 00 00    mov    0x2f9d(%rip),%rdi <-- 107b+2f9d=foo2@4018 
[...]
0000000000004010 <foo1>:
    4010:   04 20         <-- foo1 = @2004
[...]
0000000000004018 <foo2>:
    4018:   04 20         <-- foo2 = @2004
```

To avoid the duplication with **proposition#1**, GCC provides `-fmerge-all-constants`:

> Attempt to merge identical constants and identical variables.
> This option implies -fmerge-constants. In addition to -fmerge-constants this considers e.g. even constant initialized arrays or initialized constant variables with integral or floating-point types. Languages like C or C++ require each variable, including multiple instances of the same variable in recursive calls, to have distinct locations, so using this option results in non-conforming behavior.

Let's rebuild **proposition#1** with this flag. We can see that *foo2* is optimized out, only *foo1* is kept and referenced:

```
$ gcc -fmerge-all-constants f.c f1.c f2.c
$ objdump -D a.out
[...]
0000000000001149 <main>:
    1149:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    114d:   55                      push   %rbp
    114e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1151:   48 8d 3d b0 0e 00 00    lea    0xeb0(%rip),%rdi <-- 1158(RIP) + eb0 = 2008 <foo1>
    1158:   e8 f3 fe ff ff          callq  1050 <puts@plt>
    115d:   48 8d 3d a4 0e 00 00    lea    0xea4(%rip),%rdi <-- 1164(RIP) + ea4 = 2008 <foo1>
    1164:   e8 e7 fe ff ff          callq  1050 <puts@plt>
    1169:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
[...]
0000000000002008 <foo1>:
    2008:   53    'S' <--- foo2 optimized out, only foo1 defined
    2009:   41    'A'
    200a:   4d    'M'
    200b:   45 5f 'E' '_'
    200d:   56    'V'
    200e:   41    'A'
    200f:   4c 55 'L' 'U'
    2011:   45    'E'
```

Comment: Even if they are declared in 2 different files?

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer with the code disassembly.

Comment: Thank alot, is this a compiler dependant optimization ?

Comment: I discussed for GCC. Don't know for others. I updated my answer with details about the GCC options (-fmerge-constants = default and -fmerge-all-constants). With the second one, even your code proposition gets optimized.

Answer (score 2):

Read a C standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). It requires that   `foo1 != foo2` when that test happens at runtime (after of course `extern const char foo1[]; extern const char foo2[];` declarations). It could accept that a compiler optimizes `if (foo1==foo2) abort();` (or `assert(foo1 != foo2);` after some `#include <assert.h>`, see [assert(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html)...) to a no-op.

> Wanted to understand if in the final binary this will be optimized to take common space in memory.

#### This is *very compiler specific*.

Perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked [as](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -flto -O3` (and probably `-fwhole-program`) at both compile and link time could optimize that.

If memory space is very important in your project, consider writing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) -or some [GNU Binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) extension- to detect (and perhaps optimize) that case. Such a plugin could use some [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) database (at compile time) managing all the global `const char` definitions.

Notice that the optimization you want requires that the compiler did detect that pointer equality like `foo1 == foo2` is *never* tested (and that with `const char*p1, *p2;` it never happens that `p1` is `foo1`, `p2` is `foo2` and pointer equality `p1 == p2` is tested at runtime of your program). You could use tools like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) to ensure that.

What more compilers do are transforming

```
const char foo1[] = "SAME VALUE";
const char foo2[] = "VALUE";
```

to the equivalent of

```
const char foo1[] = "SAME VALUE";
const char foo2[] = foo1 + 5; //// since strlen("SAME ") is 5
```

My suggestion is to *generate C code* in your build procedure, document it very well, and *explicitly* share such data.

Another approach could be to use your preprocessor (maybe above [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp)) or write your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) defining some `__builtin_my_shared_string` compiler builtin.

You commented later:

> Code is being generated by a tool/script and there are many such constants and files.

Then just improve that tool/script to generate better code. Your C generating tool could use some [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) database.

PS. AFAIK, both GCC and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) can do such an optimization, but I am not sure. And since they are open source, you could improve them.

PPS. Your problem could be a use case for the [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) static source code analyzer and related to both [CHARIOT](http://chariotproject.eu/) and [DECODER](http:///https://www.decoder-project.eu/) projects. It seems more difficult than what you think. You could contact the persons in charge of these projects.

Comment: /GF will do it for MSVC.  It is on by default for release builds in Visual Studio.

Comment: I heard that GCC does that too. You need to check

Comment: I'm pretty certain it does, but I have been stuck programming with MSVC for years, and probably will be for another while. :(